# calloc only return arrays of size 8

Tags: c, double, calloc

I'm trying to create arrays of doubles in C, such that every array has d doubles in it (the user inputs d). I tried using calloc to allocate the memory for each array:

```
double *vec;
vec = (double*) calloc(d, sizeof(double));
```

For some reason it only generates arrays of doubles of size 8 (i.e. it generates a "blank" array of size 8 with only zeroes in it: [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]).

I even tried putting a specific number in the calloc call (for example, 3) - but still it only returns an array of size 8.

Comment: You should declare vec as a pointer : `double *vec;`

Comment: How exactly do you determine that it "only return arrays of size 8"?

Comment: You don't show a [mre] so we can only guess what you mean that the size is `8`. And my ***guess*** is that you use `sizeof(vec)`, which gives you the size of the *pointer*, not what it might point to. Either that, or `sizeof(*vec)` which is the same as `sizeof(vec[0])` and gives the size of the first element only.

Comment: You cannot determine the size of an array from a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Very likely duplicate: [How to find the size of an array (from a pointer pointing to the first element array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-pointing-to-the-first-element-a) That is: there is no way to obtain information from calloc regarding how much memory it allocated. Because _you already know how much it allocated_, namely `d*sizeof(double)` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`calloc` does not return an array. It returns a pointer. The pointer points to the first byte of memory that has been reserved in response to the `calloc` request.

The reservation is invisible. You cannot see how much space is reserved.<sup>1</sup> A memory reservation is implemented by accounting in internal data structures shared by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `free`, and related routines.

Because `calloc` clears the memory it reserves, if *n* bytes are requested and granted, the first *n* bytes of memory at the pointed-to address will contain zeros. Bytes beyond that may or may not contain zeros, because `calloc` does not guarantee anything about the contents of memory beyond that or whether it is reserved for use or not.

The fact that the contents of memory beyond the first *n* bytes do or do not contain zeros cannot be used to determine that that memory was or was not allocated or prepared by `calloc`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Some C implementations may provide routines that report information about how much space is reserved and/or may provide documentation about how much space is reserved. For example, an implementation may document that each reservation is padded to a multiple of 16 bytes.